# Optimizing to minimize the difference between two normalized vectors. What metric to use?

Tags: optimization, geodesic, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to minimize the difference between two normalized vectors of dimension $N$. Currently, I am using an $L_2$ normalized distance.

Since the vectors are normalized, they should sit on some hypersphere. Hence, it doesn't seem to make sense to use the Euclidean metric. Rather, I should use something that takes the distance to "walk on" that hypersphere, but not "through" it. What metric should I use?

Comment: You may want to learn about geodesic metric. But optimization problems with it are slightly harder then normal convex optimization. There are some generalization of convexity for Riemann spaces that may come useful.

Comment: If they sit on a hypersphere, your optimization problem is not convex anyway.

Comment: So, you have two points on a hypershere and you would like to find the length of the shortest path living on the hypersphere whose endpoints are the two given points, right?

Comment: The geodesic distance between two unit vectors $u$ and $v$ is $\cos^{-1}(u\cdot v)$. However, for optimization purposes this is equivalent to the Euclidean distance $\|u-v\|$, in the sense that $\cos^{-1}(u\cdot v)$ increases whenever $\|u-v\|$ increases and vice versa. So it makes no difference whether you minimize the geodesic distance or the Euclidean distance, or even the squared Euclidean distance (which is easiest to work with).

Comment: ic..any papers that prove this? When you are close on the hypershere, wouldnt geodesic distance be more numerically stable?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you have two subsets $A,B$ of the sphere in $\mathbb{R}^N$ (where sphere is the set of norm $1$ vectors with respect to the normalized $L_2$ norm, I gather). You are trying to find $\inf_{x\in A, y\in B} d(x,y)$ and your question is asking what distance $d$ corresponds to the shortest path that stays on the surface of the sphere instead of going inside of it. The metric you are looking at is the geodesic distance on the sphere (and in general, shortest path metrics are called geodesic distance).

However, if you solve the problem of finding $u\in A$ and $v\in B$ such that $\|u-v\|=\inf_{x\in A, y\in B}\|x-y\|$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the normalized $L_2$ norm, the same pair of points will minimize the geodesic distance. Indeed, for two pairs of points $(u,v)$ and $(x,y)$ on the sphere, the walking distance between $u$ and $v$ on the surface of the sphere is less than (or equal to) the walking distance between $x$ and $y$ on the surface of the sphere if and only if the direct ($L_2$) distance between $u$ and $v$ is less than (or equal to) the direct ($L_2$) distance between $x$ and $y$. More specifically, if you know one of the distances (walking/$L_2$) between $u$ and $v$, you can find the other. Since both distances are invariant under orthogonal transformations, you can assume that $u$ and $v$ are both on the circle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (by applying a suitable orthogonal transformation).